# gulp-babel transpile from >=ES6 to ES5

Tags: babeljs, gulp-babel

I have been unable to transpile ES6 to ES5 using gulp-babel.

This seems to be an open issue on [github/babel/gulp-babel](https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel/issues/167).

**However, I was able to get this working well with browserify [Refer a sample I made](https://github.com/MaheshSasidharan/gulp-babel-browserify)**

But I am trying to use the [gulp-babel](https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel) package

I have the following setup.
Which is what I have been using, but I still get just a minified file with all `require` lines in it.

`gulpfile.js`

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const babel = require("gulp-babel");
const sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
const uglify = require("gulp-uglify-es").default;
const concat = require("gulp-concat");

gulp.task("buildjs", () => {
  return gulp.src(paths.js.source)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
    .pipe(concat(paths.build.destMinJSFileName))
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(paths.build.destMapFolder))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build.destBuildFolder));
});
```

---

`.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

---

`package.json`

```
"@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
"gulp": "^4.0.0",
"gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
"gulp-uglify-es": "^1.0.4"
```

---

`entry.js` *(paths.js.source)*

```
require("@babel/polyfill");
require("./main")
```

---

`bundle.min.js` *(actual output)*

```
"use strict";require("@babel/polyfill"),require("./main")
//# sourceMappingURL=maps/bundle.min.js.map
```

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out, that is is expected. Babel would only transpile ES6 and above to ES5.

Module like browserify or webpack needs to be used in order to get the require module working.

[Here](https://github.com/MaheshSasidharan/gulp-babel-browserify/blob/master/gulpfile.js) is an example

Answer (score 0):

Please check your babel and gulp-babel version.

If you are using babel version 6, you need to explicitly install/use gulp-babel version 7.

If you are using babel version 7, you need to gulp-babel version 8 which you can get `npm run i --save-dev gulp-babel` for now.

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel
>
> Babel 7:
>   `npm install --save-dev gulp-babel @babel/core @babel/preset-env`
>
> Babel 6:
>   `npm install --save-dev gulp-babel@7 babel-core babel-preset-env`